# Why is this generic json function not working?

Tags: swift

Looking to make a function to decode any Type that I pass in at the call site.. so of course it has to be generic over the type. So far my implementation looks like this:

```
func getAll<ResourceType>(_ type: ResourceType, using url: URL, completion: @escaping ([ResourceType] -> Void) where ResourceType: Codable {
 
     //This works just fine
    
}
```

but when I try to call it:

```
getAll(Movie, using: URL(string: "movies.com")) { movies in
     
 //This does not work 
 //Error says Type 'Movie.Type' cannot conform to 'Decodable`
 //Error says Type 'Movie.Type' cannot conform to 'Encodable`
 

 // This baffles me because in the func declaration it says *where RT: Codable*
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`type` must be `ResourceType.Type`, the generic `ResourceType` can be both a single object and an array

```
func getAll<ResourceType>(_ type: ResourceType.Type, using url: URL, completion: @escaping (ResourceType) -> Void) where ResourceType: Codable {
```

and when calling the method `type` must be `[Movie].self`

```
getAll([Movie].self, using: URL(string: "movies.com")) { movies in
```

and a parentheses is missing in the signature of the method and the compiler with complain about an unwrapped URL

Comment: Or simply remove the type parameter `func getAll<T: Decodable >(using url: URL, completion: @escaping (T) -> Void) {` and explicitly set the resulting type `getAll(using: URL(string: "movies.com")!) { (movies: [Movie]) in`